# How do i create two conditions in one mysql field?

Tags: mysql, eclipse, mysql-workbench, birt

Sorry I did not know how to word the question, it's actually a little more complicated than it sounds. I've got the following in my database; please see screenshot in the link:

http://prntscr.com/utyopv

I am generating a report using BIRT and I want that when priority = 2, it displays a value of 'High'. Similarly when priority = 1, it shows 'Medium' and when it = 1, it shows 'Low'.

But I also want that when estimated_time = 4, it displays '16+hrs', when estimated_time = 3, it shows '< 16 hrs' etc etc.

Now I've managed to do the priority using the code below;

```
SELECT date_created, CONCAT(first_name, " ", last_name) as user, e_name, cc_name, 'High' as priority, job_description, due_date, estimated_time, impediment
FROM job_planning as jp
INNER JOIN user as u
ON jp.user_id = u.id
INNER JOIN employer as e
ON jp.employer_id = e.id
INNER JOIN client_company as cc
ON jp.client_id = cc.id
WHERE jp.priority = '2'

union

SELECT date_created, CONCAT(first_name, " ", last_name) as user, e_name, cc_name, 'Medium' as priority, job_description, due_date, estimated_time, impediment
FROM job_planning as jp
INNER JOIN user as u
ON jp.user_id = u.id
INNER JOIN employer as e
ON jp.employer_id = e.id
INNER JOIN client_company as cc
ON jp.client_id = cc.id
WHERE jp.priority = '1'

union

SELECT date_created, CONCAT(first_name, " ", last_name) as user, e_name, cc_name, 'Low' as priority, job_description, due_date, estimated_time, impediment
FROM job_planning as jp
INNER JOIN user as u
ON jp.user_id = u.id
INNER JOIN employer as e
ON jp.employer_id = e.id
INNER JOIN client_company as cc
ON jp.client_id = cc.id
WHERE jp.priority = '0';
```

But how can I also include estimated_time? Can i use OR in mysql? I cannot use AND because then it would separate the two.

Thanks and appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT ... , 

       CASE priority WHEN 2 THEN 'High'
                     WHEN 1 THEN 'Medium',
                     ELSE        'Low'
                     END AS verbal_priority,

       CASE estimated_time WHEN 4 THEN '16+hrs'
...
```

Comment: Wow just found this out now was about to post! Thanks though @akina!!!